# Spark environment variables in log4j ConversionPattern

Tags: apache-spark, log4j, log4j2

Here's my log4j configuration:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, loggerId
log4j.appender.loggerId=org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.loggerId.rollingPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy
log4j.appender.loggerId.rollingPolicy.ActiveFileName=${spark.yarn.app.container.log.dir}/spark.log
log4j.appender.loggerId.rollingPolicy.FileNamePattern=${spark.yarn.app.container.log.dir}/spark_%d{dd-HHmm}.log.gz
log4j.appender.loggerId.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.loggerId.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %p %t %c usecase=${spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.usecase} usecase2=${spark.executorEnv.usecase} logdir=${spark.yarn.app.container.log.dir} - %m%n
log4j.appender.loggerId.encoding=UTF-8
```

In the `ConversionPattern` key, I can see `logdir` value but not `usecase` or `usecase2`. When I go to Spark UI, I can see `spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.usecase` & `spark.executorEnv.usecase` values are set. These values are set during `spark-submit`. My only guess is these values are set after log4j is instantiated, that's why there are no values. If that's the case, how can I set spark environment variables sooner? Or is there another way around this?

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?

Comment: @BruceRitchie unfortunately no, going to spark 3 should help though